# Defining a macro to automate putting Minted environments into tabular

Tags: tables, macros, environments, minted, code

I want to make a macro, `\mintedInOutTable`, that puts some code into a minted environment and then puts that in a tabular (for example, to show input and output to a REPL).

For this code,

```tex
\mintedInOutTable{2 + 2}{4}
```

I want the output to look something like this (with Minted's syntax highlighting):

[image]

Here is what I tried (with the `array` package loaded):

```tex
\newcommand{\mintedInOutTable}[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.8\textwidth}}
        In & \begin{minted}{Python}#1\end{minted} \\
        Out & \begin{minted}{Python}#2\end{minted}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Are your snippets of Python code just one-liners? If not you have quite a big problem and some more details are needed.

Comment: They are one-liners. The previous version of your comment, which suggested replacing `\begin … \end` with `\mintinline`, worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your snippets are one-liners, use `\mintinline`. But it's also possible to cope with longer code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\mintedInOutTable}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}w{l}{0.1\textwidth}w{l}{0.8\textwidth}@{}}
        In & \mintinline{python}{#1} \\
        Out & \mintinline{python}{#2}
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newsavebox{\pythonbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{longmintedInOutTable}{m}
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{lrbox}{\pythonbox}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
  \begin{minted}{python}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}w{l}{0.1\textwidth}w{l}{0.8\textwidth}@{}}
    In  & \usebox{\pythonbox} \\
    \noalign{\vspace{\dp\strutbox}}
    Out & \mintinline{python}{#1}
  \end{tabular}%
}
  

\begin{document}

\mintedInOutTable{2 + 2}{4}

\begin{longmintedInOutTable}{Hello, Jack}
def greet(name):
    print ('Hello', name)

greet('Jack')
\end{longmintedInOutTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you changed my `p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.8\textwidth}` to `@{}w{l}{0.1\textwidth}w{l}{0.8\textwidth}@{}`? What do the `@` and `w{l}` tokens do?

Comment: @BenZ.  With `@{}` one suppresses the intercolumn material; `w{l}{<dimen>}` specifies a fixed width cell with no line break allowed and left alignment. Better than `p` for this case.